# execute string as javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My object has a call back:

```
var MyObject = {
CallBack: "function (whichSubMenuIsClicked, subMenuObjectTag) { self.doStuff(whichSubMenuIsClicked.SubMenuItem, whichSubMenuIsClicked.HeaderColumnName, whichSubMenuIsClicked.DivIdentifier);}",
}
```

The callback is a string. Now I need to execute it using MyObject.CallBack(param1, param2)
How can this be done using jquery or javascript. The self in this case is the original widget calling another widget. Thus the call back is on the original widget.

Comment: WTH would you write a function as a string if it shell be used as a function?

Comment: In case not all the answers are clear, **you should not be doing this**. If you are receiving a function in JSON and therefore it needs to be a string, then **you shouldn't be receiving a function in JSON**. This approach needs to be reconsidered. It is inefficient and, as with any use of `eval`, insecure.

Comment: @zetlen: It is only insecure when the source of the string can't be trusted - as with every script. Also have a look at [When is eval() not evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi you are absolutely right. Opening up a new execution context has its own security problems, but they are edge cases compared to the overall problems with running any untrusted code.

Comment: @zetlen: You are receiving all/many functions as string: downloading them as .js file by a browser request. The key here is: can the source trusted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Function` constructor, which accepts a list of parameter names followed by the function body:

```
var MyObject = {
    CallBack: "self.doStuff(whichSubMenuIsClicked.SubMenuItem, whichSubMenuIsClicked.HeaderColumnName, whichSubMenuIsClicked.DivIdentifier)",
};

var myfunc = new Function("whichSubMenuIsClicked", "subMenuObjectTag", MyObject.CallBack);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just don't have the function as a string.

Have the function as a function:

```
var MyObject = {
   CallBack: function (whichSubMenuIsClicked, subMenuObjectTag) {
                  self.doStuff(whichSubMenuIsClicked.SubMenuItem, whichSubMenuIsClicked.HeaderColumnName, whichSubMenuIsClicked.DivIdentifier);
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the function as a function, as @Curt demonstrated. Only if you really have no other choice than getting it as a string (e.g. from user input), you would first need to parse it to executable code which you then could call. The way to do so is [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). A problem will become the reference `self`, which is not a variable inside your function and would be assumed global. Yet, you can use a [`with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to work around that:

```
var MyObject = {
    CallBack: "function (whichSubMenuIsClicked, subMenuObjectTag) { self.doStuff(whichSubMenuIsClicked.SubMenuItem, whichSubMenuIsClicked.HeaderColumnName, whichSubMenuIsClicked.DivIdentifier);}",
};
var widget = {doStuff: console.log};
var fn;
with( {self: widget} ) {
    fn = eval( MyObject.CallBack );
}
fn({SubMenuItem: "…", HeaderColumnName: "…", DivIdentifier: "…"});
```

Comment: You don't need eval, the `Function` constructor is purpose built for this.

Comment: @Asad: Is it? Where is the difference? Also, the OP already has a full function string, and not a parameter list + function body code. Also, the `Function` constructor does not seem to be able to handle the `self` variable.

Comment: The difference is that the Function constructor will never execute any statements passed to to it, whereas the `eval` function would execute any malicious statements sneaked in. This is pretty much the entire point behind the hubbub over the use of `eval`. I'm not sure what you mean by "handling the `self` variable".

Comment: Of course `Function` does not execute any line of code - only you execute the resulting function. And malicious statements could be "sneaked" into a function body as well, there's no difference.

Comment: Here's the difference: `eval('function(){};alert("LOL")')` vs. `new Function('//note that you can't sneak in code that will be immediately executed')`

Comment: The `myfunc` your code generates references a `self` variable - which seems to be implied as global there. With `eval` and `with` you can assign a local variable. Try my function.

Comment: @Asad: Ouch. Of course you would execute that function, otherwise you wouldn't need to generate it. `var myfunc = new Function('alert("LOL!");'); myfunc();`

Comment: Yes, but I'm not talking about what the callback contains. My point is that it will always return a function, and not unexpectedly execute other code. If you have a callback that alerts `"LOL"` on loop, so be it, this is no different from property assigning `CallBack: function(){while(true){alert("LOL");}}`. We're not discussing the merits of what is in the function itself, we're talking about the ways of constructing it. At least `Function` follows a contract, and doesn't arbitrarily execute the code passed in.

Comment: Sure, that's true. So if malicious code were injected, just the point of the unexpected execution would differ. However, I think `eval` is suited better for the OP's current problem (we still don't know the actual task) as it allows handling of variable scope and the OP already has a full `"function(){…}"` string which does not need to be parsed before.

Answer (score -2):

Very bad approach but You can do it by `eval()`

```
var MyObject = { CallBack: "AName = function(param1, param2) { alert(param1 + param2); }", }

eval(MyObject.CallBack+"(1,2)");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DqZpa/)

Comment: If the only solution to your problem is eval, change the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, "Never" really?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You certainly don't have to use it here, but there are indeed times when `eval` is useful. Metaprogramming, for instance!

Comment: @Starx yup never. I edited my comment as you changed your answer, but you should never use eval.

Comment: I didn't downvote you by the way as this does solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't deserve a downvote; yes `eval` is terrible, but this answers the OP's question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, __NEVER__ is too much I think :P

Comment: @JeffreySweeney Does it though? OP wants to pass 2 parameters to that function. `MyObject.CallBack(param1, param2)`

Comment: @Starx You don't really need the `eval` even within the ridiculous constraints of the problem. You can use the `Function` constructor.

Comment: @Curt, Unquestionably yours is the right approach for many reason. Including the `parameter` problem you just mentioned.

Comment: @Starx That aside, I still don't think this would run. Your code snippet isn't passing parameters.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney: No, it does. The variable of the OP is named `MyObject`, and also this code tries to call a string - resulting in a TypeError only.

Comment: @Bergi, This was a stupid answer to start with. I have updated with working answer.